# Is it normal and good practice to enlarge the amount of columns when adding new features

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relational-modelling

There is a table named is A with 40+ columns, among which around 10 are columns of hierarchical levels, in a data analysis platform maintenance and development ( *legacy* ) project. Due to development of a new feature, the hierarchical structure would need ten more extra levels, e.g. level11, level12, ..., project manager decided to add 20 new columns to that existing table A.

The hierarchial level data is sth like a revenue description by country and department: For instance,

-- value of level1: `USA 100 | JAPAN 200 | UK 300`

---- value of level2: `USA SOFTWARE 50 | USA HARDWARE 50 | OTHERS JAPAN 50 | ...`

------ value of level3: `SOFTWARE A 10 | SOFTWARE B 10 ... | HARDWARE A 100 | HARDWARE B 200 ...`

Each level's value is the breakdown of its parent level' value and there is no redundancy. So it is normalized, isn't it?

As a developer, I intuitively feel uncomfortable to add 20 more new columns to an existing table with already 40+ columns. But when considering the current table with 40+ columns works pretty fine, I am not able to argue with a sufficient reason against the idea of adding 20 more new columns to the existing table A.

**Question: is adding that many columns to an existing table with already 40+ columns a very normal practice? What is the pros and cons in this approach?**

Comment: It's not really about the number of columns and more about whether your schema is properly [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The common guidance is to ensure your schema is normalized, unless you have measured that it needs to be denormalized for performance reasons.

Comment: @VincentSavard The new columns to be added are of the same type of data but just about data from different levels, so the table is indeed normalized, doesn't it really matter with that many columns?

Comment: @Rui the fact that you have 30 columns holding the same kind of data suggests that your schema probably **isn't** normalized although I am currently too lazy to check it against the definition of the word "normalized"

Comment: What do you mean by "hierarchical levels" "data from different levels"? That doesn't sound normalised to me

Comment: @Caleth I explained the meaning of "hierarchical levels" also in the question description. It is normalized, isn't it?

Comment: @Rui no, that isn't normalised at all. Normalised would be to only have the bottom level of data. Every other "layer" would be a query

Comment: how do you manage to go more than 10 levels deep? By level 10 you are probably already talking about individual screws in the hardware

Comment: @user253751 exactly, see the description, say the decision of adding 10 levels more made by the project manager is how we currently go more than 10 levels deep. It can work, but will always cause about more coding when adding more levels

Comment: @Rui And do all the levels apply at each row? So a single row contains "USA", "USA SOFTWARE", "SOFTWARE A" and then another row contains "USA", "USA SOFTWARE", "SOFTWARE B"?

Comment: @user253751 all levels apply at each row, i.e. `USA`, `USA SOFTWARE`, `SOFTWARE A`, `SOFTWARE B` are all in one row, so when adding more values to deeper levels, would need to add more corresponding columns to the table A

Comment: @Rui wait, why are SOFTWARE A and SOFTWARE B in the same row?

Comment: @user253751 because they both belongs to `SOFTWARE` on its parent level, and the row is just a description on revenue breakdowns. The existing table is like that

Comment: @Rui so it sounds like your entire revenue breakdown takes up one row? How do you put SOFTWARE A and HARDWARE A in the same row?

Comment: @user253751 good question :) as u can see from the description of this question. atm values such as `SOFTWARE A` and `HARDWARE A` are put into different columns of the same row

Comment: @Rui how does the software know that HARDWARE A is part of HARDWARE and not part of SOFTWARE?

Comment: @user253751 moreover, analysts keep using and analyze data on such table with that many columns for more than 10 years already, so they are used to this

Comment: @user253751 good catch again :) The purpose of that table is not to know the relationship at all but just to know that one column has value `SOFTWARE | HARDWARE`, then the next column will have the next level of value `SOFTWARE A | SOFTWARE B | HARDWARE A | HARDWARE B`. I know this might sound absurd, but analysts just need such information, they are not interested in "HARDWARE A is part of HARDWARE" or not. I also feel it is not that good to have that many columns, but I am not able to prove that such data is not normalized

Comment: Wait, how many rows are in this table? It sounds like you are adding columns instead of adding rows

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand, you have been following the pattern that your project manager has been imposing for a while, there may be valuable reasons for that decision to be made, have you tried asking him why their design for DB administration works like that? Honestly I don't see the point on organizing tables this way, but again, your DBA coworkers might answer that to you (and I hope you would be so kind as to share that answer with us, for mutual knowledge, after all that's what this community is all about and you don't need to if it involves confidential data).

While working on the database, I would suggest creating different tables, each with its own purpose and being related by foreign keys, but if you need to insert more columns (as such relationships may be very difficult to design and mantain in some specific situations), I don't see any real problem expanding the tables besides readability, the problem starts when updates are made to the properties of existing columns, same with any programming language, a good project should be expansible, but its properties shouldn't need to change by such expansions.

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns is okay. Sometimes you just have a lot of columns. But what's concerning is that you have a lot of *the same* columns. You don't have actually different bits of data like first name, last name, street number, street name, postal code, date of birth, date hired, ...... - what you have is more like first name 1, first name 2, first name 3, first name 4, first name 5, first name 6, first name 7, ......

In this case (a many-to-one relationship of first names to rows) you should create a FirstName table whose rows each hold one first name, and the ID of the row they are associated with.

If the overhead of a separate table is unacceptable *and you don't need to use the first names in queries and you don't expect to have a large number of first names in a row* then you can instead have a FirstNames column which stores all the names in some format, such as JSON. Then you are treating the whole collection of names as one value, so it can be expensive if you have a very large number, and the database engine can't efficiently index the individual values, but it can be okay if you don't need those things.

Option 0 (bad because you have a maximum number of first names):

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TeamID | GoatsTeleported | FirstName1 | FirstName2 | FirstName3 | FirstName4 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      0 |              47 |      Alice |        Bob |      Carol |       Dave |
|      1 |            6542 |        Eve |      Frank |      Grace |      Heidi |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Option 1 (most flexible, adds another table):

```
+--------------------------+
| TeamID | GoatsTeleported |
+--------------------------+
|      0 |              47 |
|      1 |            6542 |
+--------------------------+

+--------------------+
| TeamID | FirstName |
+--------------------+
|      0 |     Alice |
|      0 |       Bob |
|      0 |     Carol |
|      0 |      Dave |
|      1 |       Eve |
|      1 |     Frank |
|      1 |     Grace |
|      1 |     Heidi |
+--------------------+
```

Option 2: (no extra table, but you can't query according to first names)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| TeamID | GoatsTeleported |                      FirstNames |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|      0 |              47 |  ["Alice","Bob","Carol","Dave"] |
|      1 |            6542 | ["Eve","Frank","Grace","Heidi"] |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```